# Putting ViewPager and tabs in a fragment and replacing it

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment

In my main activity I have a `ViewPager` with two tabs and each of them has its contents in a fragment. One of the tabs holds a list of items and when I press on an item from that list I want the details of that item to appear on the screen. I thought of putting the whole `ViewPager` in a fragment and when the user taps the item the fragment representing the whole `ViewPager` is replaced with another fragment representing the details of the item. Is it possible and is it a good practice? Maybe I should just start another activity with the details of the item?

Answer (score 0):

How you do it is your own choice. It's perfectly fine to switch your Fragments.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new FragDetails())
                    .addToBackStack(FragPager.class.getName()).commit();
```

Switching to another Activity is fine too, you just have more of a "flicking" screen when opening a new Activity (and some other life cycle stuff too of course). If you don't want that, switch Fragments.

Comment: But is it really possible to properly configure a `ViewPager` from within a fragment? I mean I need to set the navigation mode to tabs and so on. Is it possible to do from within a fragment? And also a reference to actionbar from fragment?

Comment: Of course you can, you can get everything from within your Fragment, even the ActionBar! `getActivity().getActionBar()` is your friend. ;-) You can also use inner fragments to have a hierarchy of fragments that host other fragments (like one hosting a ViewPager).